# Filter the rows in CSV file based on column values of two CSV files using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files:

Each of them has three columns: time, X and Y. 
I want to retain the rows of both files which has same time(intersection of column 0) and delete the rows with different time.

For example:

**a.csv**

```
time                      x          y

2018/01/01/01:00:45:03    3          4

2018/01/01/01:00:45:05    4.5        5

2018/01/01/01:00:45:06    5         5.5

2018/01/01/01:00:45:08    5.5       6.5
```

**b.csv**

```
time                     x   y

2018/01/01/01:00:45:01  3.5 4.5

2018/01/01/01:00:45:05  5.5 5.5

2018/01/01/01:00:45:06  8   6.5

2018/01/01/01:00:45:09  10  9
```

**expected output **c.csv****

```
time                    x   y

2018/01/01/01:00:45:05  5.5 5.5

2018/01/01/01:00:45:06  8   6.5
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `loc` statement with `.isin()`:

```
c_csv = b_csv.loc[b_csv['time'].isin(a_csv['time'])]
```